# How to embed webrtc video call application from a https website into my website

Tags: firebase, webrtc, twilio-click-to-call, simplewebrtc, openwebrtc

I am working on WebRTC video call using Twilio and Firebase as described in this [blog post](https://www.sitepoint.com/real-time-video-chat-room).

My website (e.g. http://example1.com) doesn't have SSL certificate and so this application cannot use my camera and microphone. So I am thinking of getting another domain with SSL (e.g. https://example2.com) and putting this application there.

Thereafter I want to embed this application (https://example2.com) into http://example1.com, but I am not sure if by after embedding https://example2.com on http://example1.com, it will still be able to access the camera and microphone.

So basically, I want to create something like [this](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-08-25-webrtc-video-chat-app-in-20-lines-of-javascript/), where we can just embed the pubnub code into any website, irrespective of SSL certificate.

Also how do I pass the userid from my website to the application? TIA

Comment: You'll need https across the board.  When you state: "where we can just embed the pubnub code into any website, irrespective of SSL certificate", note that "any website" will need https too for this to work.

Comment: If certs in general are your problem, what about something like https://letsencrypt.org/ ?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do will be difficult, because CORS is one thing, and mixing http/https is not recommended.

You are better off just going with https across the board. Get yourself a wildcard SSL certificate, so that any site eg, www.abc.example1.com, www.def.example1.com will all be supported.